# How do I postfix '+tag:<keyword>' to a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, shopify

I have a Shopify store and I'd like to use the search form to filter based on tags. According to the [Shopify documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-store/dashboard/storefront-search#searching-specific-fields) I have to "Prefix a term with a field name and colon to narrow your search for that term to the specified field.".

The default search form looks like this:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">

  <input type="search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="Zoeken naar..." aria-label="Search all products">
  <button type="submit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
    <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="fallback-text">Zoeken</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

When a search for `celavita` is preformed, the url looks like this:

```
http://store.<redacted>.com/search?type=product&q=celavita
```

What I want is for the url to end up like this:

```
http://store.<redacted>.com/search?type=product&q=celavita+tag:Jumbo
```

I've tried this:

```
<form action="/search" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">

  <input type="search" name="q" value="{{ search.terms | escape }}" placeholder="Zoeken naar..." aria-label="Search all products">
  <input type="hidden" name="tag" value="Jumbo">
  <button type="submit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
    <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="fallback-text">Zoeken</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

But this results in the url looking like:

```
http://store.<redacted>.com/search?type=product&q=celavita&tag=Jumbo
```

What could I try next? Could this be done using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like you need Javascript to override the form submission, edit the URL parameters and do a `window.location=` with the new result.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do something like this. (Untested)

```
$(".search-bar").submit(function(){
var type=$("input[name='type']").val();
var q=$("input[name='q']").val();
var tag=$("input[name='tag']").val();
var url="http://store.<redacted>.com/search?type="+type+"&q="+q+"+tag:"+tag;
window.location = url;
return false;
});
```